# How can I determine with script which textures are attached to a blender material?

Tags: python, blender

I am loading and cleaning a lot of legacy .fbx files.  I need to import the fbx file, check for repeated meshes, materials, and textures and then select the material that has textures that are attached to bitmaps.  (Out of 5 fbx files, only one has the usable material/texture)

I can import the fbx files, find the redundant materials, but I cannot figure out which textures are attached to the materials, and then which textures have bitmaps.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be materials[i].active_texture.  I asked a little too soon.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on what you discovered -

I expect the fbx format supports more than one image per material and as a blender material can have more than one texture associated with it, a more complete search could be performed with the following

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for matslot in obj.material_slots:
        for texslot in matslot.material.texture_slots:
            if texslot is not None and texslot.texture.type == 'IMAGE':
                if texslot.texture.image is not None:
                    print('object', obj.name, 'has material',
                        matslot.material.name, 'that uses image',
                        texslot.texture.image.name)
                    print('It is saved at', texslot.texture.image.filepath)
```